# Unsure of why I do not call the return type here in my void function definition

Tags: c++, function

I am learning C++. I am following along with a learning tutorial. After creating (forgive me if I am not labeling this correctly) a function that calculates exponentials with the for() loop. We are learning how to use a void function to call it. In all of the code there are few times the parameters (hopefully labeling correctly) do not include the return type.
It is creating an itch for me as I really am taking things slow trying to understand everything so far.

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
double power_function(double base, double exponent)
{double solution = 1; 
    for(double i = 0; i < exponent; i++) 
    {solution = solution * base; 
    }
    return solution;
}

void print_power(double base, double exponent)
 { double void_operation = power_function(base,exponent); 
/* Why do we call without the return type? Cause it is already defined? */
std::cout << "The base of " << base << " with an exponent \n.";
 std::cout << " of " << exponent << " is equal to " << void_operation; 
}

int main () 
{int base test, exponent test; 
std::cout << "What is the base,\n."; 
std::cin >> base_test; 
std::cout << "What is the exponent?\n.";
std::cin >> exponent_test; 
printpower(base_test, exponent_test); 
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an image of the code.

Comment: I apologize about that, I am working to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

When you call functions in C++ you don't need to specify the return type because it's already specified in the function definition above.

Here's a really simple example of this from cplusplus.com

```
using namespace std;

int addition (int a, int b)
{
  int r;
  r=a+b;
  return r;
}

int main ()
{
  int z;
  z = addition (5,3);
  cout << "The result is " << z;
}
```

`addition()` has return type int but when its called

`z = addition (5,3);`  the return type is not specified.

Comment: Thanks very much! I appreciate the detailed feedback that was very simply put. I also realize now the main function in my example is also calling the void function without the return type also, either way your example explains that also as it is the same. PS I upvoted you but I am new so it isn't public lol :)

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyondHaha No worries on the upvote! Glad you got a better understanding and good luck learning C++. Stay positive and take breaks

Answer (score 0):

First, a function should be declared:

```
double power_function(double base, double exponent)
```

This tells the compiler that a function exists named `power_function`, which takes two `double` parameters, and returns a double. (The definition might immediately follow, or the definition might be elsewhere, but that's not relevant int his case) From then, on, the compiler knows the parameter types, and the return type.

So when the compiler sees:

```
double void_operation = power_function(base,exponent);
```

The compiler will generate code to copy both those parameters as doubles to the stack (converting them to `double` if needed), and then call the function.  When the function returns, the compiler already knows the return type is a `double`, so it will take the top item on the stack as a `double` and will assign it to `void_operation` (again, converting from `double` if needed).

Comment: Thanks very much. I appreciate the thorough explanation and thorough edit of my post. I wasn't sure if I was to leave the entire code present, I am glad you did, as it shows the whole picture for anyone down the road in a similar boat as you know :)

Comment: @UVBakesandBeyond: The key piece was that your original image had the `double power_function(double base, double exponent)`, but your typed version didn't, and it turns out that's super relevant to the answer.